# MDP in Salesforce for Service folks

Tags: force.com-sites

Can you please help me out on how MDP is going to address Field Service People? Is there any more information on this?

Thanks,
Jones

Comment: What do you mean by MDP??

Comment: Multi Dimensional Publisher